# How to get coordinates from depthImage

Tags: ros, depth-image, camera-depth-points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am working with depthImages. This is my first time with camera models, so I do not understand how to get the information I need from camera_info topic.

My inputs are a CameraInfo and a Image(depthimage) topics.
I need to get the coordinates (in odom frame) of one of the pixels.

Can anyone explain me how to do it?
I have tried too much things but the results are wrong. I think it may be because of the matrices that define the camera or the focal length... but I am lost in this field.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195737/how-to-get-coordinates-from-depthimage/) by [arebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20562/arebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How you would do it in python (not tested) given a CameraInfo message *info*, pixel coordinates *(u, v)*, and the depth at those coordinates, *d*:

```
import image_geometry, numpy
cam_model = image_geometry.PinholeCameraModel()
cam_model.fromCameraInfo(info)
ray = numpy.array(cam_model.projectPixelTo3dRay((u,v))
point3d = ray * d
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2